# Check if the result list is the same as the expected list after insert and delete elements in a list

Tags: c

I'm doing a basic `linked-list` program. Now I have this code below in the main method to check if the list operations have the expected result.

For example when I insert at the beginning of the list the elements are `{50, 70, 80, 100, 77, 200, 44, 70, 6, 0}`. I expect the list with these elements `{0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50}`, when then I insert in the middle the elements are `{5, 20, 10, 30, 7, 8, 2, 104, 1, 22}`, after the element "200",  I expect the list as `{0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 22, 1, 104, 2, 8, 7, 30, 10, 20, 5, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50}`. And I want the same when I insert an element at the end of the list and for delete operations.

So, I want to show a message "Correct" when the result of operations and expected result are equal, and "Incorrect" if its different. But I'm not having success doing this. Can you help to understand how this can be achievable ?

This is the code I have, What I have commented is what I was trying to achieve my goal for the first case (insert at the begin) :

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int listsize=10;

    int arrBegining[] = {50, 70, 80, 100, 77, 200, 44, 70, 6, 0};
    int arrBeginingExpected[] = {0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50};

    int arrMiddle[] = {5, 20, 10, 30, 7, 8, 2, 104, 1, 22};
    int arrMiddleExpected[] = {0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 22, 1, 104, 2, 8, 7, 30, 10, 20, 5, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50};

    int arrEnd[] = {40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 76, 4 , 0, 80, 2};
    int arrEndExpected[] = {0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 22, 1, 104, 2, 8, 7, 30, 10, 20, 5, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50, 40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 76, 4, 0, 80, 2};

    int arrDeleteSpecificExpected[] = {0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 22, 1, 104, 2, 8, 7, 30, 10, 20, 5, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50, 40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 4 , 0,  80 ,2};
    int arrDeleteFromEndExpected[] = {0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 22, 1, 104, 2, 8, 7, 30, 10, 20, 5, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50, 40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 4, 0};

    // int newArr[] = {};

    for(i=0;i<listsize;i++){
        insert_at_begning(arrBegining[i]);
        // newArr[i] = arrBegining[i];
    }
    // if(newArr == arrBegining){
       // printf("Correct");
    // }

    // else{
       // printf(Incorrect);
    // }

    for(i=0;i<listsize;i++){
        insert_at_middle(arrMiddle[i], 200);
    }
    for(i=0;i<listsize;i++){
        insert_at_end(arrEnd[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<listsize;i++){
        delete_from_middle(76);
    }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        delete_from_end();
    }

    display_file(FILEDIR);

    return 0;
}
```

Restant code, this code is working, Im just in doubt in the main method:

```
void insert_at_begning(int value)
{
    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    var->data=value;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=var;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        var->next=head;
        head=var;
    }
}

void insert_at_end(int value)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=head;
    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    var->data=value;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=var;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        var->next=NULL;
        temp->next=var;
    }
}

void insert_at_middle(int value, int loc)
{
    struct node *var2,*temp;
    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    var->data=value;
    temp=head;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=var;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->data!=loc)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        var2=temp->next;
        temp->next=var;
        var->next=var2;
    }
}

int delete_from_middle(int value)
{
    struct node *temp,*var;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data == value)
        {
            if(temp==head)
            {
                head=temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                var->next=temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    printf("data deleted from list is %d",value);
}

int delete_from_end()
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        var=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(temp ==head)
    {
        head=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("data deleted from list is %d",temp->data);
    var->next=NULL;
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to create a linked list, and for that we should define a new type which is member of our list and can be linked to other members. it is something like this:

```
typedef struct SMember{
    int data;
    struct SMember *next;
    struct SMember *previous;
}Member;
```

now we should have a header for our list to count and get first and last members for insertion requirements, like this:

```
typedef struct sList{
    int count;
    struct SMember *first;
    struct SMember *last;
}List;
```

so we can use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct SMember{
    int data;
    struct SMember *next;
    struct SMember *previous;
}Member;

typedef struct SListHeader{
    int count;
    struct SMember *first;
    struct SMember *last;
}ListHeader;

void InsertAtBegning(int value, ListHeader *list)
{
    Member *newMember = (Member *)calloc(1, sizeof(Member));
    newMember->next=NULL;
    newMember->previous=NULL;

    newMember->data = value;
    if(list->count==0)
    {
        list->count = 1;
        list->first = newMember;
        list->last = newMember;
    }
    else{
        Member *tempMember;

        list->count++;
        tempMember = list->first;
        list->first = newMember;
        newMember->next = tempMember;
        tempMember->previous = newMember; 
    }
}

void InsertAtMiddle(int value, int middle, ListHeader *list)
{
    Member *newMember = (Member *)calloc(1, sizeof(Member));
    newMember->next=NULL;
    newMember->previous=NULL;

    newMember->data = value;
    if(list->count==0)
    {
        list->count = 1;
        list->first = newMember;
        list->last = newMember;
        return;
    }
    else{
        int i;
        Member *tempMember;

        for(i=0, tempMember = list->first; i < list->count; i++, tempMember=tempMember->next)
            if(tempMember->data == middle)
            {
                if(tempMember->next != NULL)
                {
                    Member *tempMemberNext = tempMember->next;
                    tempMember->next = newMember;
                    newMember->next = tempMemberNext;
                    newMember->previous = tempMember;
                    tempMemberNext->previous = newMember;
                }
                else{
                    tempMember->next = newMember;
                    newMember->previous = tempMember;
                    list->last = newMember;
                }
                list->count++;
                return;
            }
        //if we dont find the middle member we dont insert this member!
        free(newMember);
    }
}

void InsertAtEnd(int value, ListHeader *list)
{
    Member *newMember = (Member *)calloc(1, sizeof(Member));
    newMember->next=NULL;
    newMember->previous=NULL;

    newMember->data = value;
    if(list->count==0)
    {
        list->count = 1;
        list->first = newMember;
        list->last = newMember;
    }
    else{
        Member *tempMember;

        list->count++;
        tempMember = list->last;
        list->last = newMember;
        newMember->previous = tempMember;
        tempMember->next = newMember; 
    }
}

void DeleteFromMiddle(int middle, ListHeader *list)
{
    if(list->count==0)
    {
        return;
    }
    int i;
    Member *tempMember;

    for(i=0, tempMember = list->first; i < list->count; i++, tempMember=tempMember->next)
        if(tempMember->data == middle)
        {
            if(tempMember->next != NULL && tempMember->previous != NULL)
            {
                Member *tempMemberNext = tempMember->next;
                Member *tempMemberPrevious = tempMember->previous;
                tempMemberPrevious->next = tempMemberNext;
                tempMemberNext->previous = tempMemberPrevious;
            }
            else if(tempMember->previous == NULL && tempMember->next == NULL)
            {
                list->first = NULL;
                list->last = NULL;
            }
            else if(tempMember->next == NULL)
            {
                Member *tempMemberPrevious = tempMember->previous;
                tempMemberPrevious->next = NULL;
                list->last = tempMemberPrevious;
            }
            else if(tempMember->previous == NULL)
            {
                Member *tempMemberNext = tempMember->next;
                tempMemberNext->previous = NULL;
                list->first = tempMemberNext;
            }
            free(tempMember);
            list->count--;
            return;
        }
}

void DeleteFromEnd(ListHeader *list)
{
    if(list->count==0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else{
        Member *lastMember;

        list->count--;
        lastMember = list->last;
        list->last = lastMember->previous;
        if(lastMember->previous != NULL)
        {
            Member *beforeLastMember = lastMember->previous;
            beforeLastMember->next = NULL;
        }
        free(lastMember);
    }
}

void PrintList(ListHeader *list)
{
    int i;
    Member *tempMember;

    for(i=0, tempMember = list->first; i<list->count; i++, tempMember = tempMember->next)
    {
        printf("Member [%d] = %d\n", i, tempMember->data);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ListHeader list;
    list.count = 0;
    list.first = NULL;
    list.last = NULL;

    InsertAtBegning(1, &list);
    InsertAtBegning(2, &list);
    InsertAtBegning(3, &list);

    InsertAtMiddle(4, 1, &list);
    InsertAtMiddle(5, 2, &list);
    InsertAtMiddle(6, 5, &list);

    InsertAtEnd(7, &list);
    InsertAtEnd(8, &list);
    InsertAtEnd(9, &list);

    printf("==================================1\n");
    PrintList(&list);

    DeleteFromMiddle(1, &list);
    DeleteFromMiddle(2, &list);
    DeleteFromMiddle(3, &list);
    DeleteFromMiddle(4, &list);
    DeleteFromMiddle(5, &list);
    printf("==================================2\n");
    PrintList(&list);
    DeleteFromMiddle(6, &list);
    DeleteFromMiddle(7, &list);
    DeleteFromMiddle(8, &list);
    DeleteFromMiddle(9, &list);
    printf("==================================3\n");
    PrintList(&list);

    InsertAtBegning(1, &list);
    InsertAtBegning(2, &list);
    InsertAtBegning(3, &list);

    DeleteFromEnd(&list);

    printf("==================================4\n");
    PrintList(&list);
}
```

===========================================================

**EDIT**

===========================================================

After your comment I made some changes in your main and added two functions,

please check this out

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *head;

void insert_at_begning(int value)
{
    struct node *var;

    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    var->data=value;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=var;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        var->next=head;
        head=var;
    }
}

void insert_at_end(int value)
{
    struct node *temp, *var;
    temp=head;
    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    var->data=value;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=var;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        var->next=NULL;
        temp->next=var;
    }
}

void insert_at_middle(int value, int loc)
{
    struct node *var,*var2,*temp;
    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    var->data=value;
    temp=head;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=var;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->data!=loc)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        var2=temp->next;
        temp->next=var;
        var->next=var2;
    }
}

int delete_from_middle(int value)
{
    struct node *temp,*var;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data == value)
        {
            if(temp==head)
            {
                head=temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                var->next=temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    printf("data deleted from list is %d\n",value);
}

int delete_from_end()
{
    struct node *var, *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        var=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(temp ==head)
    {
        head=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("data deleted from list is %d\n",temp->data);
    var->next=NULL;
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}

int check_results(int expected[], int count)
{
    struct node *temp;
    int i;

    if(head==NULL)
        return -1;

    if(expected[0]!=head->data)
        return -1;
    i=1;
    temp = head->next;
    while(temp->next != NULL && i<count)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        if(expected[i]!=temp->data)
            return -1;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void printResults()
{
    struct node *temp;

    if(head==NULL)
        return;

    temp = head;
    printf("Results:");
    printf(" %d ", head->data);
    temp = head;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        printf(" %d ", temp->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int listsize=10;

    int arrBegining[] = {50, 70, 80, 100, 77, 200, 44, 70, 6, 0};
    int arrBeginingExpected[] = {0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50};

    int arrMiddle[] = {5, 20, 10, 30, 7, 8, 2, 104, 1, 22};
    int arrMiddleExpected[] = {0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 22, 1, 104, 2, 8, 7, 30, 10, 20, 5, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50};

    int arrEnd[] = {40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 76, 4 , 0, 80, 2};
    int arrEndExpected[] = {0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 22, 1, 104, 2, 8, 7, 30, 10, 20, 5, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50, 40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 76, 4, 0, 80, 2};

    int arrDeleteSpecificExpected[] = {0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 22, 1, 104, 2, 8, 7, 30, 10, 20, 5, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50, 40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 4 , 0,  80 ,2};
    int arrDeleteFromEndExpected[] = {0, 6, 70, 44, 200, 22, 1, 104, 2, 8, 7, 30, 10, 20, 5, 77, 100, 80, 70, 50, 40, 30, 20, 1, 7, 4, 0};
    // int newArr[] = {};

    for(i=0; i<listsize; i++)
    {
        insert_at_begning(arrBegining[i]);
    }

    printResults();
    if(check_results(arrBeginingExpected, 10))
        printf("correct!\n");
    else
        printf("incorrect!\n");

    for(i=0; i<listsize; i++)
    {
        insert_at_middle(arrMiddle[i], 200);
    }

    printResults();
    if(check_results(arrMiddleExpected, 20))
        printf("correct!\n");
    else
        printf("incorrect!\n");

    for(i=0; i<listsize; i++)
    {
        insert_at_end(arrEnd[i]);
    }

    printResults();
    if(check_results(arrEndExpected, 30))
        printf("correct!\n");
    else
        printf("incorrect!\n");

    for(i=0; i<listsize; i++)
    {
        delete_from_middle(76);
    }

    printResults();
    if(check_results(arrDeleteSpecificExpected, 29))
        printf("correct!\n");
    else
        printf("incorrect!\n");

    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        delete_from_end();
    }

    printResults();
    if(check_results(arrDeleteFromEndExpected, 27))
        printf("correct!\n");
    else
        printf("incorrect!\n");

    //display_file(FILEDIR);

    return 0;
}
```

the result is:

```
Results: 0  6  70  44  200  77  100  80  70  50
correct!
Results: 0  6  70  44  200  22  1  104  2  8  7  30  10  20  5  77  100  80  70  50
correct!
Results: 0  6  70  44  200  22  1  104  2  8  7  30  10  20  5  77  100  80  70  50  40  30  20  1  7  76  4  0  80  2
correct!
data deleted from list is 76
data deleted from list is 76
data deleted from list is 76
data deleted from list is 76
data deleted from list is 76
data deleted from list is 76
data deleted from list is 76
data deleted from list is 76
data deleted from list is 76
Results: 0  6  70  44  200  22  1  104  2  8  7  30  10  20  5  77  100  80  70  50  40  30  20  1  7  4  0  80  2
correct!
data deleted from list is 2
data deleted from list is 80
Results: 0  6  70  44  200  22  1  104  2  8  7  30  10  20  5  77  100  80  70  50  40  30  20  1  7  4  0
correct!
```

Comment: It was too long so I don't write compare, if it is useful tell me so I add it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer really. Sorry, I didnt put in the question the other part of the code that I already have. I already have the insert and delete operations. Its just in the main method that Im not see how can I do what I want.

Comment: @Jax It seems you have a linked-list in your program which you want to fill it with   your inserts and then compare its results with the desired array of integers. am I right?

Comment: @Jax your insert and delete functions seem to have some bugs, I only code what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your help really, but it still dont works. Because it shows always the message "incorrect".

Comment: It seems that is for example, in the insert at begin, the element "50" is not in the result list, because the first Result is empty: 

Results:
Results: [70]
Results: [80]  [70]
Results: [100]  [80]  [70]
Results: [77]  [100]  [80]  [70]
Results: [200]  [77]  [100]  [80]  [70]
Results: [44]  [200]  [77]  [100]  [80]  [70]
Results: [70]  [44]  [200]  [77]  [100]  [80]  [70]
Results: [06]  [70]  [44]  [200]  [77]  [100]  [80]  [70]
Results: [00]  [06]  [70]  [44]  [200]  [77]  [100]  [80]  [70]
Results: [00]  [00]  [06]  [70]  [44]  [200]  [77]  [100]  [80]  [70]
incorrect!

Comment: I change the for to i<=listsize but the issue continues. And in the last result as you can see above have two "0" elements and should be only one "0".

Comment: Thanks for your help. But there is some issues, because in the first result the element 50 dont appears, in the next result the 50 element also dont appears and in the next result the element "3" dont appear.

Comment: @Jax Check this one please

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a modular approach: Create a new function which returns the boolean value true if "correct" and false if else. Pass the "expected list" as parameters to the function and either declare the edited list as a global variable or also pass it as parameters; I'd suggest you to pass it as parameter too. In the function body, loop through all elements of one array and check if a particular element is present or not using nested loops which returns true only at the end of function and false if one element is not found in another array.
So basically the prototype is as follows:

bool check(int expected[], int list[]);

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution seems good but how to do the comparison? To check if the expected array is icual to the actual array?

Comment: @Jax bool found; for (int i=0;i<sizeof(list)/sizeof(int);i++) { found=false; for (int j=0;j<sizeof(expected)/sizeof(int);j++) { if (list[i]==expected[j]{ found=true; break; } else { continue;}} if (!found) return false; } return true;

Comment: @Jax Hope that helps.